# How to make 2 FutureBuilders wait on the same Future in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a `Future` which, when complete, adds some data to a `ChangeNotifierProvider`. Then I use the data in the ChangeNotifierProvider to populate some `ListViews`.  The thing is, I have 2 screens that both get the data they need from that same Future. Each screen has a FutureBuilder that return a ListView.
**How do I make the 2 FutureBuilders wait on the "same" future, without calling it 2 times?**
Is FutureProvider a solution?

Comment: Do you want to merge two Future?

Comment: Like 2 API call merge into one

Comment: I have 2 screens, and each screen has a FutureBuilder as a body. The problem is that the 2 FutureBuilders have the same Future, lets say fetchData(). My question is how to avoid calling fetchData() 2 times, I want to call it just once and I want the 2 FutureBuilders behave in the same manner, waiting for that single call to complete.

Comment: In this case you should  use Stream with broadcast

Comment: You should be able to make any number of `FutureBuilder`s wait on the same `Future` as long as you have a reference to that `Future` (e.g. by storing in a variable).

Comment: So I just need to call the future like : `MyClass().myFuture()` ?

Comment: You don’t call a future. `myFuture` in your comment is probably a method that returns a future. So you should call it only once to create only a single future and use that value in both FutureBuilders. Using a provider would be a good way to create a value once and provide it to several other widgets. Either Provider(create: (_) => createFuture()) to provide the future and is it in future providers or FutureProvider(create: (_) => createFuture()) to provide the value that the future completes to (I think it will provide null until the Future completes)

Answer (score 1):

you can find a solution when using a variable.
let's say that fetchData() is your function in your provider class.

`Future<void> initializeData = provider.fetchData(); //fetchData called here`

now use

> initializeData

variable as a future in all the FutureBuilders

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: initializeData,
  builder: (ctx, snapShot) {} );
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Future.wait` API, what it does is to wait until all futures are complete and it returns its results or errors.

See this as example:

```dart
  Future<String> getData() async {
    final future1 = Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => "I am");
    final future2 = Future<int>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 100);
    final future3 = Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => "Years old!");
    final results = await Future.wait([future1, future2, future3]);

    // Doing a simple cast considering my Future will never fails in this example, you should check for exceptions/errors!
    final future1ResultOrError = results.first as String;
    final future2ResultOrError = results[1] as int;
    final future3ResultOrError = results[2] as String;
    return "$future1ResultOrError $future2ResultOrError $future3ResultOrError";
  }
```

You use it like a single Future:

```dart
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              initialData: null,
              builder: (context, shot) {
                return Text(shot.hasData ? shot.data : "Waiting for data...");
              },
            ),
```

This will print: "I am 100 Years old!". Notice how it loads the data from different Futures!

#### Edit:

You may want to have a single Future and provide it to the two FutureBuilder. See the code bellow:

```dart
class _MyState extends State<MyPage> {

  Future mySingleFuture;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    final future1 = Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => "I am");
    final future2 = Future<int>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 100);
    final future3 = Future<String>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => "Years old!");
    final results = await Future.wait([future1, future2, future3]);

    // Doing a simple cast considering my Future will never fails in this example, you should check for exceptions/errors!
    final future1ResultOrError = results.first as String;
    final future2ResultOrError = results[1] as int;
    final future3ResultOrError = results[2] as String;
    return "$future1ResultOrError $future2ResultOrError $future3ResultOrError";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mySingleFuture = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              initialData: null,
              builder: (context, shot) {
                return Text(shot.hasData ? shot.data : "Waiting for data...");
              },
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              initialData: null,
              builder: (context, shot) {
                return Text(shot.hasData ? shot.data : "Waiting for data 2...");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand this case, but my problem is the opposite. I have 2 screens, and each screen has a FutureBuilder as a body. The problem is that the 2 FutureBuilders have the same Future, lets say fetchData(). My question is how to avoid calling fetchData() 2 times, I want to call it just once and I want the 2 FutureBuilders behave in the same manner, waiting for that single call to complete.